# xenserver (xcp-ng) 7.6 slow export - TAPDISK high cpu usage - xen orchestra

Tags: xenserver

I have a problem with high cpu usage by TAPDISK in xenserver - to be precise - in xcp-ng, I've posted the problem on xcp-ng forum but I didn't recieved any valid help from the creators of xcp-ng (...). Any way, the problem is when exporting (copying) a VM from one host to anonther, or copy VM within the same server the copy speed is extremly slow. Extremly slow I mean few MB per second. I dig the interent I've found that high TAPDISK usage could be connected to TCP offload of NIC card, but I'm new to xenserver and IDK if this is the way. Problem is that I've already stared production, and I have a problem with slow export (slow backup).

the setup is:

- the test is within one dell r510 server with perc h700
- local storage (8x8TB wd reds)
- two raids - raid10 and raid5
- xen orchestra sits on raid10 volume
- DR backup test - from raid10 to raid5 volume
- Two Intel X5675 CPUS, 128 GB RAM

TAPDISK almost 100% cpu usage during export

```
x Top Processes Procs=0 mode=3 (1=Basic, 3=Perf 4=Size 5=I/O)qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqx
x  PID       %CPU    Size     Res    Res     Res     Res    Shared    Faults   Command                                    x
x             Used      KB     Set    Text    Data     Lib    KB     Min   Maj                                            x
x     8432    95.8   46716   10604     228    7580       0  2884      0      0 tapdisk                                    x
x     7346    44.7 5596512  362032   24020 5499448       0 24308      3      0 xapi                                       x
x      105     5.0       0       0       0       0       0     0      0      0 kswapd0
```

Link to forum thread:
https://xcp-ng.org/forum/topic/2036/extrlemy-slow-backup-speec-about-few-mb-s/20

Comment: Not clear in the forum if you tried changing the connection of XOA to your XCP server to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. You say you are accessing XOA via HTTP but that's irrelevant.  Check this post which is clearer on what that means: https://xcp-ng.org/forum/topic/1200/remove-backup-bottleneck-please-report/9

Comment: For the record: XCP-ng is mostly a packaging of open-source XenServer. So they don't "make it" perse.